# Monochromatic infinity operads as algebras over the "operad operad"

Tags: homotopy-theory, infinity-categories, operads

In the "ordinary" operad category, it is known that there is a colored operad $Op$ with set of colors $\mathbb{N}$ corresponding to "degrees" of vertices and with operations indexed by trees, such that algebras over $Op$ in $\mathrm{Set}$ (or more generally any symmetric monoidal category) correspond to monochromatic operads.

Is it known that $\infty$-algebras over $Op$ are equivalent to monochromatic $\infty$-operads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, combine Corollary 9.4.1 and Theorem 7.11 of [arXiv:1410.5675](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5675), for example.

This topic is also examined more explicitly
in the work of Chu and Haugseng, [arXiv:1707.08049](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08049).

Corollary 5.1.13 shows that enriched ∞-operads are equivalent
to ∞-algebras over the operad of colored operads.

Theorem 5.2.10 proves (using [arXiv:1410.5675](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5675)) that the underlying ∞-category
of the relative category of ordinary enriched colored operads
is equivalent to the ∞-category of enriched colored ∞-operads.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! Can you give a rough idea of how these imply the result? Am I correct in understanding that you observe that simplicial operads and sOper-algebras give two model category structures on the same category and the free object transferability result of Corollary 9.4.1 implies they are Quillen equivalent?

Comment: @DmitryVaintrob: I added references to the work of Chu and Haugseng, which combines these results to get more-or-less exactly the statement that you asked for.

Comment: Thank you! That certainly seems to settle it. Interestingly enough, I had recently read the first couple of sections of the Chu-Haugseng paper, but didn't notice this theorem.